# How to install realtime kernel?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, realtime

[Axel](https://askubuntu.com/users/499/axel) [wrote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4762/how-to-set-up-video-and-audio-players-to-use-realtime-or-close-priority/4763#4763): *"try using the a realtime kernel, it's more responsive and the apps "seems to hang less""*.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like rt (and preemp and lowlatency) still haven't landed in the repositories. Maverick is still beta... are you sure you want to try such special kernels in this stage?

I've found a message which covers the issue of which low latency kernels you want to try and, perhaps, a PPA to get it: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2010-March/009323.html

Be cautious, though... There be dragons!

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install linux-rt`

Edit: Previously add the ppa in the other reply, and try: `sudo apt-get install linux-realtime`

Answer (score 1):

This won't do since there are NO 10.10 MAVERICK packages in the PPA! Only Lucid and Natty (11.04)! This is what worked for me:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10072326&postcount=10

Answer (score -1):

Repository for Maverick here:

https://launchpad.net/~stephane-brunner/+archive/maverick

Comment: Welcome to AU! Consider expanding your post by summarizing what can be found on the link target page. Read more on Meta:  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3149/when-is-is-not-appropriate-to-use-links-in-answers